# scipy Bundle Adjustment

Tags: scipy-optimize, least-squares

I am attempting to add ground control points (contraints) to the [scipy Bundle Adjustment](https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/bundle_adjustment.html) implementation.

With the example [dataset](https://grail.cs.washington.edu/projects/bal/ladybug.html) of 49 images, 7776 3D points and 31843 image observations; if we ***make*** the last point a fixed parameter in the Bundle Adjustment how would the `fun()` change?

```py
def fun(params, n_cameras, n_points, camera_indices, point_indices, points_2d):
    """Compute residuals.
    
    `params` contains camera parameters and 3-D coordinates.
    """
    camera_params = params[:n_cameras * 9].reshape((n_cameras, 9))
    points_3d = params[n_cameras * 9:].reshape((n_points, 3))
    points_proj = project(points_3d[point_indices], camera_params[camera_indices])
    return (points_proj - points_2d).ravel()
```

Or would the `bundle_adjustment_sparsity()` change?

```py
def bundle_adjustment_sparsity(n_cameras, n_points, camera_indices, point_indices):
    m = camera_indices.size * 2
    n = n_cameras * 9 + n_points * 3
    A = lil_matrix((m, n), dtype=int)

    i = np.arange(camera_indices.size)
    for s in range(9):
        A[2 * i, camera_indices * 9 + s] = 1
        A[2 * i + 1, camera_indices * 9 + s] = 1

    for s in range(3):
        A[2 * i, n_cameras * 9 + point_indices * 3 + s] = 1
        A[2 * i + 1, n_cameras * 9 + point_indices * 3 + s] = 1

    return A
```

Where the last point is:

```py
print(len(points_3d))
print(points_3d[-1])
7776
[-0.74800017  0.03709491 -4.8131693 ]
```

and the corresponding observations (on the images) are:

```py
print(len(points_2d))
X = points_2d
print(point_indices)
31843
[   0    0    0 ... 7774 7775 7775]
```

```py
sa = np.zeros( len(X), dtype=[('I',np.int64), ('X',np.float64,(2))] )
sa['I'] = I
sa['X'] = X
sa['X'][sa['I'] == 7775]
array([[-281.64   ,   24.15002],
       [ 202.2    ,   26.34998]])
```

Which means 3D point 7775 was observed in two images.
I understand some type of *weight* would be needed to account for the control point, that will be taken as fixed, but how would you code and execute this please?